# Choosing FPGA with enough inputs

Tags: fpga

I need a FPGA that can have 50 I/O pins. I'm going to use it as a MUX. I though about using MUX or CPLD but the the guy I'm designing this circuit for says that he might need more features in the future so it has to be a FPGA.

So I'm looking for one with enough design examples on the internet. Can you suggest anything (for example a family)? 
Also if you could tell me what I should consider when picking, that would be great. I'm new to this and still learning.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very open question, and the answer to it as stated can be very long, if possible at all given all the options. What I suggest to you is to make a list of all current and future requirements. This will help you communicate your needs (here and elsewhere) and force you, and the people you work with on this project, to think about them more carefully. Saying that "more features in the future" will be needed is meaningless; would you buy the most capable FPGA on the market? No.

When you've compiled this list and thought about the requirements, post them here again, and then you'd get plenty of help.

Another possibility to get feedback and help is to describe what you are trying to do/solve. Maybe an FPGA is not the best solution -- people here will tell you that.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Saar, but you have to go back one step further: when you decide which technology to target, keep in mind that an FPGA needs a lot of things to run, i.e. different voltages fore core, I/O, auxiliary, and probably more. Also you need some kind of configuration mechanism as an FPGA is in general (there are exceptions) SRAM based and therefore needs to be configured at startup. CPLDs are less flexible but much easier to handle...